# Segmentation Fault in A Doubly Linked List Display Function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, queue, doubly-linked-list

So I have a program that takes an `int` for input, and inserts the integer into a doubly linked list where the functions are `createQueue`, `enqueue`, `dequeue`, `display`, `peek`, and `destroyQueue`. I have a `main.c` and a `queue.h` file but the problem doesn't lay in there, it's in the `queue.c` file. The problem is when I pipeline a `test12.txt` file and print to an `output.txt` with the following commands, `enqueue 0 0 display`, I get a segmentation fault. If I run just `enqueue 0 0` in the `test12.txt` file there's no problem, it works just fine. My question is, am I dereferencing `temp` in `display` when it points to nothing when I write `temp = temp->prev;` or is that a valid call and my problem lies in the initialization of my `temp` node?

**queue.c** file:

```
#include "queue.h"

Queue_ptr createQueue() {
    Queue_ptr s = (Queue_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    s->front = NULL;
    s->back = NULL;
    return s;
}

void enqueue(Queue_ptr s, element e) {
    DN_ptr n = (DN_ptr)malloc(sizeof(DLLNode));
    n->e = e;
    if (s->front == NULL) {
        n->next = NULL;
        s->front = n;
        s->back = n;
    }else{
        s->back->next = n;
        n->prev = s->back;
        s->back = n;
    }
}

element dequeue(Queue_ptr s) {
    DN_ptr temp = s->front->next;
    element e = s->front->e;
    free(s->front);
    s->front = temp;
    s->front->next = NULL;
    s->front->prev = NULL;
    return e;
}

int isEmpty(Queue_ptr s) {
    if (s->front == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

element peek(Queue_ptr s) {
    return s->front->e;
}

void display(Queue_ptr s) {
    DN_ptr temp = s->back;
    while (temp) {
        printf("%d\n", temp->e);
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
}

void destroyQueue(Queue_ptr s) {
    DN_ptr temp = s->front;
    DN_ptr next;
    while (temp) {
        next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = next;
    }
    free(s);
}
```

**queue.h** file:

```
#ifndef queue_h
#define queue_h

#include "stdheader.h"

//Structures

//element is content of a node.
typedef int element;

//_DLLnode is 1 link in a doubly linked list.
struct _DLLNode {
    element e;
    struct _DLLNode *next;
    struct _DLLNode *prev;
};

typedef struct _DLLNode DLLNode;
typedef struct _DLLNode *DN_ptr;

//DLL is a series of links tracked by the head and back of the list.
struct _DLL {
    DN_ptr front;
    DN_ptr back;
};

typedef struct _DLL Queue;
typedef struct _DLL *Queue_ptr;

Queue_ptr createQueue();
void enqueue(Queue_ptr, element);
element dequeue(Queue_ptr);
int isEmpty(Queue_ptr);
element peek(Queue_ptr);
void display(Queue_ptr);
void destroyQueue(Queue_ptr);

#endif /* queue_h */
```

Comment: Post the definition of types `Queue`, `element`, `Queue_ptr`, `DLLNode`, `DN_ptr`...

Comment: I added the header file with the declaration types @chqrlie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not set `n->prev` in `enqueue` when the queue is empty, neither do you set `n->next` when the queue is not empty.

`dequeue` corrupts the queue if it has more than 2 elements, and it crashes if it has only one element.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void enqueue(Queue_ptr s, element e) {
    DN_ptr n = (DN_ptr)malloc(sizeof(DLLNode));
    n->e = e;
    n->next = NULL;
    if (s->front == NULL) {
        n->prev = NULL;
        s->front = n;
        s->back = n;
    } else {
        s->back->next = n;
        n->prev = s->back;
        s->back = n;
    }
}

element dequeue(Queue_ptr s) {
    DN_ptr temp = s->front->next;
    element e = s->front->e;
    free(s->front);
    s->front = temp;
    if (temp) {
        temp->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        s->back = NULL;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed the display to work and I think I fixed the Dequeue to work as long as it has 1 element, however you are right about if it has more than 2 elements. How should I go about fixing it to work for 2? I took s->front->next = NULL; and s->front->prev = NULL; out and it works up till 2 elements are in the que.